# Date Pipe Formatting Issue

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe

I am attempting to format my date, however I am having issues with the pipe inside of a ternary operator. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I want to use a ternary operator to say if its true then show the formatted date and if not then show the my na message. This first line formats just fine but as soon as I introduce a ternary operator it does not. I think I am writing it incorrectly.

```
[innerHTML]="myBundle.myDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy'"
```

I want it to look like this. Where am I going wrong with this line?

```
[innerHTML]="myBundle.myDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy' ? myBundle.myDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy': na | fdContent"
```

Comment: `[innerHTML]="(myBundle.myDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy') ? (myBundle.myDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy') : (na | fdContent)"` Try this one once

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: can you add what is the expected output? Also, what is the value of fdContent and na?

Answer (score 0):

try this one -

```
[innerHTML]="myBundle.myDate  ? (myBundle.myDate | date: 'MMM/dd/yyyy'): na | fdContent"
```

Comment: @rdopler what is fdContent?